# Distance to find similar samples in a multivariate dataset

Tags: clustering, multivariate-analysis, distance, similarities

Apart from Euclidean and Mahalanobis distance metrics. Given a sample with multivariable values, is there a way to find the samples that are similar to the given sample?

Does KNN clustering find the similar samples?

Thanks